# How to simulate file_get_contents('php://input') in Laravel feature testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing

i have created a function that stores a file when API PATCH endpoint is called:

```
public function patchUserImage(Request $request) : Response {
        $newImageFile = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $validator = Validator::make(['input' => $newImageFile], [
            'input' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails())
            return response(['error' => $validator->getMessageBag()->first()], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        $user = $request->user();
        $user->setImage($newImageFile);

        return response(null, Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

I am now trying to test the API endpoint in Laravel feature testing. Test looks like this:

```
public function test_patchUserImage() {
        Storage::fake("public");
        $image = UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo1.jpg');

        $response = $this->actingAsTestUser()->patch("/api/user/image", ["file" => $image]);
        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

When i run the test i get error code of 400 instead of 200. It must mean that no file was passed to function. I have tried testing the API endpoint in Postman nad it worked as expected.

[image]

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: I have never saw someone use `file_get_contents('php://input');` in modern (2013+) years... Follow Laravel standards, no need to use that old way, if you are using a framework, [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#files) and follow it, don't do magic yourself